# Prevent rebuilding of FutureBuilder from child widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

To show loading of data from firestore, I created this widget:

```
class GetDeploymentDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  const GetDeploymentDetails({required this.user, super.key});
  final User? user;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Deployment>(
      future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('deployments')
          .where("users", arrayContains: user!.email)
          .get()
          .then((value) => Deployment.fromJson(value.docs[0].data())),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: const Center(
              child: Text('No deployments found, please contact admin.'),
            ),
          );
        } else
          return AppHomeScreen(
            user: user,
            deployment: snapshot.data!,
          );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But everytime I'm making a UI change that requires rebuilding in the AppHomeScreen, the whole UI reloads and takes me back to the first page. For example, tapping on a textfield to enter some text, calls the build method of AppHomeScreen again and reloads the data of the entire app.

How can I fix this? And what is the correct way to call futures and streams in between loading of widgets while being able to show that data is loading with a circularprogressindicator.

Comment: Can you show us what's on the AppHomeScreen?

Comment: Separate the widget responsible for data fetching (GetDeploymentDetails) from the widget responsible for displaying the UI. with this only the UI widget will be rebuilt, and the data fetching widget will remain unchanged. For more information provide code for `AppHomeScreen` and who is using this `GetDeploymentDetails` class.

Comment: Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: @RandalSchwartz consider converting your comment to answer, this is correct and the most clean way so far

Comment: But I paste it as a comment three times a week at least.  People keep making this mistake.

Comment: Hi I have posted an answer as community wiki based on @Randal Schwartz comment. Can you check if it is useful or not ?<br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Randal Schwartz mentioned in the comments and the video he shared, do not build the Stream or Future Builder inside the build Widget as it will rebuild every time when a state changes.

Instead you should consider moving the constructed Future to a class instance variable as follows :

```
class GetDeploymentDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  const GetDeploymentDetails({required this.user, super.key});
  final User? user;
final constructed_future = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('deployments')
          .where("users", arrayContains: user!.email)
          .get()
          .then((value) => Deployment.fromJson(value.docs[0].data()));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Deployment>(
      future: constructed_future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
// … other stuff
}
```

Reference :

- Thanks to this video [**Fixing a common FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder problem**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg) posted by @Randal Schwartz